# How to disable links for anonymous users for SOME, but not all link items?

Tags: navigation, users

The link issue here is video links, which are for brightcove.com hosted videos. Now some important background:

- The site is a directory of company-produced videos. It requires login in order to view anything.
- However the user can assemble a list of videos (like a cart or wish list) and send a URL for that list to a non-authorized person; that person can view the video links and read text info about the video, but can't access other parts of the site.
- But some of the videos are designated as "not shareable." So even though it's OK to share links to most of the video pages and for anonymous users to play the video link, we need to exclude the "non-shareable" videos from being playable.
- The link field is only one of the fields in a node of this content type. The node itself must remain accessible to the anonymous user; it is only the video link that needs to be *variably* accessible or not accessible to anonymous.

Can anyone suggest a strategy for making some but not all video links not accessible to the anonymous user?

Comment: Follow-up: The problem with any kind of role permissions, or node or field permissions, is that the field in question needs to be available to Anonymous in MOST cases but not all. So it's a content-item-specific thing, not across all content of the type. (Also, the field is a link that's not visible to anyone, it's just associated with an index image serving as a button.) What is needed is a field in the content type that defines "shareable" or "not shareable." The state of that field would then control whether or not the link field can be used.  But I can't yet conceive of how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view of the videos and control access by role.  if you need control at the field level, I'm sure there is a module for that or you can use a field template.

Answer (score 0):

Look at People->permissions,It works by restricting access to content types based on roles.

Media is a form of content type and I guess you should be able to restrict anonymous or non registered users from viewing it but then this will also restrict viewing of images or another file uploaded as media.

If this is too restrictive you may want to create your own custom content type a panel or a page that your links link into and restrict that.